# Transform data after it received from graphql server using vue-composition api

Tags: apollo-client, quasar-framework, vue-composition-api

this is my first try of front end developing, so I mostly copy-pasting example is the net.

```
  import {useQuery, useResult} from "@vue/apollo-composable";

  export default defineComponent({
    name: 'Components',
      setup() {
          const {result: modulesResult} = useQuery(getModules)
          const result = useResult(modulesResult)
          return (result)
      }
  })
```

I've written the following code and while I can use `result` in templates (v-for or v-if), I can't find the way how to transform my data.

I want to take the value of `result` and apply transformation function and pass transformed value to templates. `result` is vue ref and value is not available if I write `ref(result).value` right after `useResult`

```
const test = ref(result).value
console.log(test) <- undefined
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

useQuery contains onResult return value, it triggers on data updates, for example

```
            const {onResult} = useQuery(getDerivativeInstruments)

            onResult((resultData) => {
                instruments.instruments = resultData!!.data.getDerivativeInstruments
                instruments.filteredInstruments = resultData!!.data.getDerivativeInstruments
            })
```